# videoJS smooth volume handle on dragging and transition on click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-video, video.js

I'm working with the videoJS plugin. I want to add transition to the volume bar so if there is a click there's an animation of transition instead of jumping directly from place to place, it's easily achievable by adding a class on the volume handle element:

```
.transition {
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

volumeHandle.addClass('transition');
```

It works on click but I want to disable it on dragging the volume handle to drag smoothly and without any transitions. I'm modifying the onMouseMove function to do this, the clean function is:

```
vjs.VolumeBar.prototype.onMouseMove = function(event) {
  if (this.player_.muted()) {
    this.player_.muted(false);
  }

  this.player_.volume(this.calculateDistance(event));
};
```

I'm doing something like:

```
volumeHandle.addClass('transition');
    if(volumeHandle.hasClass('transition')){
        setTimeout(function(){
            volumeHandle.removeClass('transition');
        },250);
    }
```

I'm using timeout to recognize click from dragging and this solution works but it is not as smooth at it is without any transitions because timeout messes things up. How can I rewrite this to work without timeout and remove transition when the volume handle is dragged and add transition when it's just a click?

I can do this only within this mouseMove method because I'm overloading it in my code.